# Testing transliteration for Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, transliteration

I am working on an android project that requires user to select something out of a given list. To facilitate user's interaction, an in-app search box is provided.

The list can have many language scripts like Spanish, CHinese, Devanagari, etc. But the user is supposed to type using standard latin alphabets only.

For example - list contains a word नमस्ते and to select this, user is supposed to type"Namaste"

To achieve above transliteration, certain database is maintained which consist of all the unicode characters and their corresponding latin alphabet characters.

Having stated the motive of the app, here is my problem -

How to test for the transliteration functionality? Manual testing is impossible as there are languages like Chinese and Mandarin involved which has exhaustive set of characters.

In order to automate this, I searched for some libraries that support back and forth translation and found [a javascript library transliteration party](http://transliterationparty.com)

I plan to translate using that and reach an equilibrium then use google translate API for phonetical reading. Is it advisable?

Any other optimal solution is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that an alphabetic solution is the best way to do this. I would better do a db containing the words in an "English transliteration" table and the corresponding words in other tables, say Mandarin, Traditional Chinese, Devanagari, Spanish, Tamil, Hiragana, ... and have another table to connect these words (i.e. ET_Word 1 is TC_Word 1554 and is De_Word 6623). In other words... I'd reason by words (instead of letters)

Comment: Thanks for replying ArtooDetoo, however I am assigned an implemented app in which I have to test the said functionality - transliteration.

I don't think at this stage any changes in backend is possible. I am looking for a way to test the implemented functionality without hving to do much manually